# Python PyMongo Count Occurrences of Array Item

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

The values I need to count are an array of values so rather than $myField being the key to an item, it's the array elements I need to count so the number of corn, wheat, barley in all the documents.

```
"myField": [
  "corn",
  "wheat"
],
```

This is the code for a single item:

```
for result in c.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$myField",
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
}]):
    print("%s: %d" % (result["_id"], result["count"]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's time for [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), which transforms an array of values into a series of documents, each with a single value where the array had been:

```
c = MongoClient().test.collection
c.delete_many({})
c.insert_many([
    {"myField": ["corn", "wheat"]},
    {"myField": ["corn", "barley"]},
    {"myField": ["hops"]},
])

for result in c.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$myField"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$myField",
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }
}]):
    print("%s: %d" % (result["_id"], result["count"]))
```

The output:

```
barley: 1
wheat: 1
hops: 1
corn: 2
```

Comment: Literally amazing!  Can't thank you enough :-) I was trying everything and would never have got that..

Comment: For Python and MongoDB skills try the MongoDB University course: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101P/about